# Is there a more core access to wxPython touch screen access? Or a way to force ZoomGesture?

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets, touchscreen

The wxPython API for GestureEvents treats zoom, pan, and rotate, as if they are distinct events which makes seamlessly switching between them impossible. Is there a way to better access the more useful information or to force it to detect every two-figure touch as a zoom gesture?

https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.GestureEvent.html

Using wxPython, I've implemented full zooming and panning and I tried to hook in the Gestures for the touch screen. The problem seems to be that the pan gesture kinda sucks. Zoom gives me ZoomFactor() which is how the distance between your two fingers but also `GetPosition()` which is actually all you need to make that also cover panning. Panning gives you Delta() but you can solve that with a variable.

The problem here is that if wxPython says I moved like a Pan Gesture at first, it's a pan function, and will not zoom. If it says I moved like a zoom first, I get full panning and zooming exactly like I want. I implemented my own matrix and use that rather nicely so I only need the information and I can crank out the correct manipulations.

Do I have to bite a bullet here and have it suck a bit? Or is there some way to force zoom-mode gesture? Is there some other way to get the more core aspects and make an API a bit more like Android TouchEvents which I could use to build this correctly?

---

https://github.com/meerk40t/meerk40t/tree/853041cb4630ffccf8d9accee5a50d95b0c9da41

```py
self.EnableTouchEvents(wx.TOUCH_ZOOM_GESTURE | wx.TOUCH_PAN_GESTURES)
self.scene.Bind(wx.EVT_GESTURE_PAN, self.on_gesture)
self.scene.Bind(wx.EVT_GESTURE_ZOOM, self.on_gesture)
```

and

```py
    def on_gesture(self, event):
        """
        This code requires WXPython 4.1. The bind will fail otherwise.
        """
        if event.IsGestureStart():
            self.widget_scene.event(event.GetPosition(), 'gesture-start')
        elif event.IsGestureEnd():
            self.widget_scene.event(event.GetPosition(), 'gesture-end')
        else:
            try:
                zoom = event.GetZoomFactor()
            except AttributeError:
                zoom = 1.0
            self.widget_scene.event(event.GetPosition(), 'zoom %f' % zoom)
```

Turning off pan doesn't make Zoom more promiscuous, it just fails to work completely in PanGesture Events.

I'm using wxPython 4.1, fallback is to not allow touch screen. This works on MSW and OSX at a minimum.

Comment: what version of wxPython/wxWidgets do you use? What OS/toolkit?

Comment: @Igor answered in question. 4.1 works fine in MSW. I just don't have any way to access more basic events.